# Is it possible to use laravel blade file as a variable?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a simple component for a styled link to be used with email templates. Since the requirement is that styling be done directly to the element I don't want to use classes. I figure I could create a PHP where `$variable = '<a href="#" style="..."><a/>'`

But what I am curious about is doing something like this:

Component:

`<a href="{{$value}}" style="">{{$display}}</a>`

Assigning:

```
$variable = @include('components.link', [
        'value' => 'https://example.com',
        'display' => 'Visit my new site!'
   ])
```

Use case:

```
$paragraph = 'Hi, if you have time '.$variable.;

@include('parent.component',[
    'text' => $paragraph
])
```

Comment: See, you can't include and assign at the same time.
.
I suggest that include the link component in the parent component and include parent component everwhere

Comment: Yea, I figured. The problem is that I may want the link in a different spot every time. If I include it in the parent component then I can't control its location every time.

Comment: If you think that is a solution, could you please write an answer for it? I'm still a bit confused as to how I would pass in a slot as data for the parent component. An example would be helpful if its not too much trouble.

Comment: I don't want to waste your time, I think you may have misunderstood what I am trying to do. I want a reusable blade file where I can pass in a link's href and display. Then I want to use that blade file as a string in another string (concatenated) because I want to pass that string into another component.